# Program to encode a loaded file and return the encoded text with key shift on python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a program that can encode a loaded file with and alphabet that is shifted by a given amount. When i try to run this portion of the program i get an error message saying "TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()"

```
    def decode(orig_de_text, key):
    orig_de_text = file_data.upper()
    text = ""
    for i in orig_de_text:
        if i in alpha:
            number = ord(i)
            number = 'number' + 'key'
            if number > ord("z"):
                number = nuumber - 26
            elif number < ord("a"):
                number = number + 26
            text = text + chr(number)
        else:
            text = text + i
    return text

def final_decode(name):
    return helper(name, key)
```

Comment: Looks like you have some errant quotes around `number` and `key` on the line where you add them together. Then on the next line you attempt to compare the string `'numberkey'` to the integer `122`.

Comment: Change the line `number = 'number' + 'key'` to `number = number + key`

Comment: I just changed the code but there is still an error saying += is an unsupported opperand. Would you know how to fix this

Comment: There's no `+=` in the new version